# Animating overlapping UIViews with large transparent areas

Tags: animation, uiview, uiimageview, cocos2d-iphone

I have a custom animation involving sliding 3 `UIView`s past one another.  Each UIView contains many `UIImageView`s.  Some of the UIImageViews have large transparent areas.  I notice that performance is significantly reduced when the UIImageVIews with large transparent areas are on-screen.  I am preloading all my images, and using image cacheing.  I doubt lazy loading would improve performance.
Is there an "easy" way to improve performance?  I tried `self.layer.shouldRasterize=YES;` and it made it *much* worse.  Would using cocos2d improve things?

Comment: Come on people!  Anyone take a punt on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cocos2d is not an "easy" way since it does not mix well with UIKit.
But if that is ok for you, yes performance could be improved a lot.
Since you mention performance, maybe UIKit isn't your best option anyway?
I guess UIKit is for simple generic interfaces and not performance heavy
stuff anyway.

Comment: OK.  Thanks @Styggentorsken.  I guess I should start looking into cocos2d.

Comment: Surprisingly little interest in this question.  Accepting @Styggentorsken 's answer as nothing better offered.